# Webpack: `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`. Using alias with trailing forward slash "@/"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, alias, bundler

I was trying to build my app with webpack and getting the error in the title of this question.

My config was:

```
module.exports = {
   mode: "development",
   entry: './src/index.ts',
   output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      clean: true,
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
         },
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
         }
      ],
   },
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
         "@/": path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/"),
      }
   },
   stats: {
      errorDetails: true
   },
};
```

I had to change the resolve property to:

```
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
         "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      }
   },
```

And it worked. I also tried to set the second argument to resolve to "./src/" and it worked. But if I remove the dot at the beginning of the string, so it is "/src" or "/src/", i get the same error.

This gives me some doubt. Does webpack have a problem when there's a `/` at the end of an alias like in "@/"? Based on the errors that i got, i seems like webpack wasn't recognizing '@/' as an alias and taking it as a literal part of the path.

An extra thing, how does the path.resolve method work? What does it do with its arguments? I've currently got no knowledge of node.js.

Comment: Did you solve it? Just encountered the same usecase.

Comment: @NeoZoom.lua [this config](https://github.com/rafaeldevvv/space-invaders/blob/master/webpack.config.js) worked fine for me, i just had to remove the leading slash, i.e. from `"@/"` to just "@", which stays like `"@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),`